# ubuntu 18.04, compiz, cairo-dock : hard to install, harder to keep in working order

Tags: 18.04

It's happened twice in the past week that I change a setting in ccsm (compiz config settings manager), I get auto-logged out, and lose the ability to start any desktop environment that supports compiz.

Then T try to install the latest ubuntu-18.04.1 (downloaded today), and it just won't install. First, it fails to detect in rufus that my USB key needs replacing, second, when I use a new USB key, today's copy of the ubuntu-18.04.1.iso installs me a read-only filesystem.

So I revert to an older copy of the Ubuntu installation ISO, and that gets me a system with write-able filesystem.

Then I install the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-install nvidia-driver-396 exfat-fuse 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins apache2 curl php libapache2-mod-php 
curl -L https://couchdb.apache.org/repo/bintray-pubkey.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb bionic main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install couchdb
```

However, this order of installation gets me a cairo-dock + gnome login option under that gears icon at the login screen (not the screen lock screen), that doesn't work, like when compiz "just breaks down".

I like Ubuntu, I like cairo-dock and compiz better than any other window manager and taskbar / startmenu combination, but stability could really be improved.

I'm currently trying a format of my 1TB SSD (takes another hour at least), then I'll try to install everything except cairo-dock first, do a reboot, then install cairo-dock, and then see if I can log in so I can use compiz and cairo-dock.

I'll update this thread when I know more.

I also know this issue requires filing bugreports to the compiz and cairo-dock guys, and I'll send them a link to this thread, but how do I get this message to the Ubuntu developers? I think someone once told me they don't read this forum.

EDIT (3 hours later) :
done :
* complete harddrive format (took over 2 hours)
* re-install of ubuntu 18.04.1 downloaded 2 weeks ago via iso image and rufus.
* install nvidia drivers, reboot, install compiz, reboot, install unity, reboot, install cairo-dock, reboot : works, can log into the cairo-dock (gnome) desktop environment. no other install sequence seems to work.
* run ccsm to tweak compiz with the 2 things i need from it : zoom without focus tracking, and the opacity brightness plugin..
---> compiz logs me out from the desktop after each change in ccsm. i set the zoom without focus tracking first, can still log in to cairo-dock desktop environment. 
----> i enable the opacity brightness plugin, and that breaks the entire cairo-dock (gnome) desktop environment, entirely.
-- resetting compiz from the unity desktop environment doesnt help

i'm now going to try a lubuntu install with the same post-installation sequence to get to cairo-dock + compiz, but i hate the fact i've already had to waste 2 days on this this week alone.

EDIT (an hour later) :

can't even get compiz to run on lubuntu, despite claims of how putting compiz --replace in the autostart of lubuntu would do the trick.

i'll try one more time with ubuntu 18.04 and compiz told to use gnome compatibility, but if that doesnt work i'm calling it quits and filing this to ubuntu devs, compiz devs and cairo-dock devs.

EDIT (2 or 3 hours later):

i can't even install ubuntu.com 18.04.1 at all anymore..

i've tried 3 different USB keydrives, i've tried using rufus and pendrive linux to make the installer usb keydrive,

what i'm getting at the moment is a 'sorry, the installer has crashed' message, the internal bugreporting that is mentioned crashes too (although it appeared to send out something during some of the N times i re-installed today), and i'm left with the following message on a black text only screen :

[0.00000] [Firmware Bug] : TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata : please update microcode to version : 0x02 (or later)

EDIT (next day, after letting that long full drive format run during sleep)

i have a working system again..

here's what it took :

- creating a new ubuntu 18.04.1 installer usb key from ubuntu.com iso (probably doesnt matter if you use rufus or pendrivelinux, i used pendrive linux) with about 280MB of persistent data storage space (dont need more and wrting to USB is sloooow).
- booting up with the usb key (done in bios menu by the way, that very first menu you get as a PC starts up) into the live environment (top menu item in the menu just after the bios menu)
- starting 'disks', and formatting all partitions on the SSD or harddrive that i want to install ubuntu on, *completely* (option erase disk, and yes, it does take 3 hours for a 1TB SSD. So if you have a smaller extra SSD lying around, that might be a better option to install the OS on). without this step, the ubuntu installer crashes. each and every time.
- installing ubuntu onto the formatted disk (without rebooting, the icon for it should be at the top-left side of your usb live desktop), with all options in the installer menu most likely irrelevant except for using the 'erase disk' option, which, just to be sure, re-creates the partitions.
- installing the video driver, compiz, ubuntu-unity-desktop (and selecting lightdm as your window manager!)
- reboot
- install cairo-dock
- use ccsm (compiz config settings manager) to enable the 'enhanced zoom desktop' and the 'opacity, brightness and saturation' plugins, setting the settings for 'enhanced desktop zoom' with special note to that plugin's 'focus tracking' tab page, where it's best to uncheck the top option ('enable focus tracking')
- run cairo-dock as an app, because if you'd boot into the cairo-dock option at the ubuntu login screen (click on the ubuntu logo of the login input window in lightdm, which should be the default startup login window now), and change the ccsm settings for cairo-dock then, that entire desktop environment crashes to the ubuntu login screen and refuses to start up again, the moment you turn off 'focus tracking' in ccsm (with the 2 mentioned ccsm plugins enabled). solution : just don't change the ubuntu login screen's ubuntu-icon menu-option at all. you'll be booting into unity lightdm and running cairo-dock as an app. you can turn on autohide at least for the default ubuntu taskbar if you like, which gives you that windows-key start-menu along with cairo-dock.

the only thing still wrong with my setup is the fact that my wallpaper changer app, variety, doesn't work with lightdm apparently. 
but maybe i can find another wallpaper changer app that does work.

lastly, i'd like to mention that the SSD i was installing on, nor the USB keys, were ever faulty hardware.

i nearly bought new disks and USB keys, if it wasn't for the fact i didn't tust 3 different USB keys that hardly get used suddenly failing one after another, nor an SSD that i've been working on for under 2 years which has never had a write failure or bad health report in an ubuntu app like 'disks'.

i was also nearly desperate enough to buy windows again, but let's just say i like ubuntu better than windows, for a bunch of reasons.

i'll forward this thread to the relevant development teams, over the next few days, if i can find their contact details.